# File download in Django template

Tags: django

I am trying to download a file, but getting the download in html format, how I can get the file in its on format

```
class Certificate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    cert = models.FileField(upload_to='cert/', blank=True, null=True)


    def download_link(self):
        self.cert.url
```

```
    <a href="{{ obj.download_link }}" download> Download File</a>
```

Tried the following way also but still in html format

```
    def download_link(self):
        path = self.cert.path
        filename = 'download.extension'
        fl = open(path, 'r')
        mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(path)
        response = HttpResponse(fl, content_type=mime_type)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
        return response
```

Comment: `self.cert.url` was not returned?

Comment: download happens in html format, that is the issue

Comment: because your `download_link` is not returning anything so, Your download button download the current page.

Comment: when I call obj.cert.url directly on template, it works, thank you all for the comments

Comment: Change `self.cert.url` to `return self.cert.url`